# Best background processing/API call approach?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, async-await

I've come up with two different approaches for handling an API call off the main UI thread, and I'm wondering which one is better in terms of performance or resource allocation. These are Android-specific examples, but I have a similar setup for iOS as well, so looking for an answer with cross-platform consideration.

**Option 1** - Kick off a new thread for the request, and handle response in the callback on the UI thread:

```
    apiTestButton.Click += delegate
    {
        progressBar1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            string response = Core.BLL.API.GetJsonTest();

            RunOnUiThread(() => ApiTestCallback(response));
        })).Start();
    };

    void ApiTestCallback(string response)
    {
        progressBar1.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

        Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, "API response: " + response, ToastLength.Long)
             .Show();
    }
```

**Option 2** - Leverage async/await:

```
    apiAsyncTestButton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        progressBar1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        string response = Core.BLL.API.GetJsonTestAsync().Result;

        progressBar1.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

        Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, "API response: " + response, ToastLength.Long)
             .Show();
    };
```

Using async/await, the code is obviously a bit more concise - no need for a separate callback method. But I'm wondering how these two options stack up in terms of performance. I assume Xamarin will translate/transform C# into platform-native logic (iOS and Android), but which would be easier for it to handle and are there performance implications?

Comment: Stick with `GetJsonTestAsync` if it's provided by the library you use, and `async/await`. Don't use an extra thread to wrap a call to `GetJsonTest`. This guideline is not Xamarin specific, BTW. On a side note, there's [`Task.Run`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run/p/System.Action/) API and you almost never need to use the low-level thread APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is different for iOS. The short answer is "Use GCD." GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) is a simple library that offers very clean management of concurrent tasks.

GCD manages a pool of system threads on your behalf.

Apple STRONGLY discourages you from using pthreads directly, since they are a critical resource and tie up physical memory and are fairly expensive to create/destroy.

(I don't know ANYTHING about Xamarin. I'm talking about native iOS development)